# How do i delete nodes in a consecutive way in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, singly-linked-list

```
void deleteNodeByKey(int k) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "Singly Linked List already Empty. Cant delete" << endl;
    }
    else if (head != NULL) {
        if (head->key == k) {
            head = head->next;
            cout << "Node UNLINKED with keys value : " << k << endl;
        }
        else {
            node* temp = NULL;
            node* prevptr = head;
            node* currentptr = head->next;
            while (currentptr != NULL) {
                if (currentptr->key == k) {
                    temp = currentptr;
                    currentptr = NULL;
                }
                else {
                    prevptr = prevptr->next;
                    currentptr = currentptr->next;
                }
            }
            if (temp != NULL) {
                prevptr->next = temp->next;
                cout << "Node UNLINKED with keys value : " << k << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Node Doesn't exist with key value : " << k << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

can someone please help me how do I delete two nodes in a row i.e. there's a link list with keys and data (1,2)->(2,3)->(3,4)(4,5)->           in this if I choose deleteNodeByKey(1) or head, it should delete the node data 2 with key 1 and after that it should delete node data 3 with key 2
so it will become something like this
(3,4)(4,5)->  please help me. Thanks!